# Tailwind css intellisense isn't working for me

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

So I had compiled my css to use tailwind, have the config file for it. But the issues is that I intellisense isn't working and when found on the output, it's show this. I don't know what this mean and any solution to it:

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBipY.png)

Comment: Try to restart the VSCode.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 I did restarted it but it still shows that

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing Tailwind CSS as a PostCSS plugin, make sure you follow [these instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

If not, disable the followings extensions and try again:

- Bootstrap 4
- Font awesome 4
- Font Awesome 5
- Pro Snippets

Comment: I don't have post css installed to my tailwind. I also don't have the other extensions listed